# Get data submitted from Login/Registration page in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am looking for any hook using which I can get the data (and perform some calculation) submitted from default Login and Registration forms of Wordpress.
I am searching for such hooks through internet but not able to find any.

Comment: `wp_login` and `register_post` not enough for what you want to achieve?

Comment: `wp_login` is deprecated and its replacement `wp_signon` is not related to capturing data from login form after submission.
`register_post` works for registration form but it only provides username and email. Is there any other hook to get all the data on registration form?

Comment: 1. You are confusing the [_hook_](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_login) with the _function_ here, I think. 2. You could access the additional form data through `$_POST` directly … that might not be the cleanest way, but [the docs explicitly give this as an example](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/registration_errors#Validating_a_Custom_Field) for validation of custom registration form fields.

Comment: I am now able to fetch data from registration form using `register_post`.
By `wp_login`, do you mean "It is a function"? I am obliged to capture login form data through hook. Is it possible?

Comment: I mean _click_ on the link I posted …

Comment: Cool... worked perfect. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, to recap:

Action hooks [`wp_login`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_login) and [`register_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/register_post) can be used to intercepts the data send by the login and registration form; although that is only for the “standard” data those forms send.

If you have enhanced these forms with custom fields, you can access their data directly in these hooks using `$_POST`. Although that might not seem to be the cleanest way, it is an approach that is [described in the WP docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/registration_errors#Validating_a_Custom_Field), so maybe there is no “better” way explicitly provided to do things like this.